# Are Extension Methods on COM objects bad?

Tags: c#, com, extension-methods, outlook-addin

I wanted to make a `.ToList()` extension method for the `Recipients` object for Outlook, but I wasn't sure if it's good practice. Would it create an extra reference to the object that would need to be cleaned up or would it be fine as long I clean up the original `Recipients` object? The extension would be used something like this.

```
private void Foo()
{
    Recipeints recipients = mailItem.Recipients //Original recipients
    if(recipients.ToList().Intersect(listOfRecipients).Any())
    { }
    OutlookEx.ReleaseComObject(ref recipients);
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<string> ToList(this Outlook.Recipients recipients)
    {
        List<string> list= new List<string>();

        if(recipients == null)
            return null;

        for (int i = 1; i <= recipients.Count; i++)
        {
            Outlook.Recipient r = recipients[i];
            list.Add(r.Name);
            OutlookEx.ReleaseComObject(ref r);
        }

        return list
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `OutlookEx.ReleaseComObject` eventually going to call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` or `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject`?

Comment: Yes,  its just a static method that calls `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)` and `o = null`.

Comment: Ok, I suspected that.  Please go research about that and be **very careful.**  For instance, if you ever have other references, even just one, to some `Recipient` you're freeing like that, you'll start getting disconnected RCW exceptions.  Most often, you're better served with forced garbage collections.

Comment: Shouldn't that only be a problem if I call `Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(o)`? If I create a reference to a `Recipient` object then call `Marshal.ReleaseComObject(o)` on it,  shouldn't the reference count only be reduced by one?

Comment: Yes.  I would add a comment inside the `for` loop anyway, so anyone changing this code in the future knows what's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Extensions methods are just static methods

Creating extensions methods do not cause an extra reference to be created, extension methods are **syntactic sugar** for static methods, they are still static methods but just allow you to call them in a more user-friendly way.

```
var ls = Extensions.ToList(recipients)
//is equivalent to 
var ls = recipients.ToList()
```

## You still need to clean up your COM objects correctly

That being said you still need to clean up and manage unmanaged resources correctly being inside of a static method, shouldn't be handled any differently than if you were implementing the method anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

An extension method is, cost wise, no different than an instance method.  An instance method has a hidden parameter pointing to self, the instance method has the same concept, only it's not hidden to the developer. The call stacks end up looking the same, and the memory pressure is the same.

In other words, if you consider it reasonable to use a function, there's no reason (other than style and reusability) to make it an extension method.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it create an extra reference to the object that would need to be cleaned up or would it be fine as long I clean up the original Recipients object?

No - extension methods are just static methods that can be called a different way.  So long as you're not storing the `recipients` parameter somewhere, it will go out of scope as soon as the method completes and will not need to be "cleaned up".  But that would be no different if it were a static non-extension method or an instance method.